# Binary multiplication -  Peasant algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I tried Binary multiplication technique on decimal numbers.

Algorithm:

To multiply two decimal numbers x and y, write them next to each
other, as in the example below. Then repeat the following: divide the first number by 2,
rounding down the result (that is, dropping the :5 if the number was odd), and double the
second number. Keep going till the first number gets down to 1. Then strike out all the rows
in which the first number is even, and add up whatever remains in the second column.

11  13

5   26

2   52

1  104

........

143 (answer)

Code:

```
class Multiply
{
static int temp;
static int sum;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int ans = multiply(x , y);
    System.out.println(ans);
}
public static int multiply(int x, int y)
{
    if(x==1)
    {
        System.out.println(x+" : "+y);
        return y;
    }


    temp = multiply(x/2, y*2);

    if(x%2==0)
    {
        System.out.println(x+" : "+y);
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(x+" : "+y);
        sum = sum+temp;
        return sum;
    }
}
}
```

Something is wrong with the recursion i think but i couldn't find what it is!!

Comment: This is commonly known as the Russian Peasant algorithm, and Google returns 'about 230,000 results for russian peasant algorithm java'.

Comment: THe method is know as Russian Peasant Multiplication.

Comment: Thanks everyone... for your answers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recursion should be like this -

```
public class Multiply {
    static int temp = 0;
    static int sum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt("11");
        int y = Integer.parseInt("9");
        int ans = multiply(x, y);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        if (x == 1) {
            System.out.println(x + " : " + y);
            return sum + y;
        }
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x + " : " + y);
        } else {
            System.out.println(x + " : " + y);
            sum = sum + y;
        }
        return multiply(x / 2, y * 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When having recursion do not use variables outside the recursive method. It is too confusing. I mean that the recursive method should be self-contained. Here is a working version of your program:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 11;
        int y = 13;
        int ans = multiply(x, y);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        if (x == 1) {
            return y;
        }    

        int temp = multiply(x / 2, y * 2);
        if (x % 2 != 0) {
            temp += y;
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't resist to post it in a single line

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
    return ((x & 1) > 0 ? y : 0) + ((x & ~1) > 0 ? multiply(x >> 1, y << 1) : 0);
}
```

Comment: Some comment would have been helpful here!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't resist to add an iterative solution: fast, simple and valid
also for negative arguments:

```
int product(int x, int y) {
    boolean positive = x >= 0;
    int p = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        if (x % 2 != 0) p += y;
        x /= 2;
        y *= 2;
    }
    return positive ? p : -p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple Java implementation which does multiplication without multiplication operator.

```
public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
    int p = 0;
    // If a is odd number. 
    if ((a & 1) > 0) {
        p = b;
    } //else use the default value in the p.

    // If 'a' contains any number larger than one
    // than continue recursion.
    if (a > 1)
        p = p + multiply(a >> 1, b << 1);
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0 || x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (x == 1) {
        return y;
    } else {
        return multiply(x >> 1, y << 1);
    }
}
```